# iOS: How get the screen cordinates (X,Y points) from opengl modelview and projection matrix?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have modelview matrix, project view matrix and position slot along with square vertices. I want to get the screen coordinates (X,Y points) of square in the iPhone screen.

```
static GLfloat rectVerts[] = {-0.1f,  -0.1f, 0.0f,-0.1f,
    0.1f, 0.0f,0.1f, 0.1f,
    0.0f,0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f
    ,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
GLKVector4 position_Vector = GLKVector4MakeWithArray(rectVerts);

float p_clip[4];
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
    p_clip[i]=0;
}
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<12;j++){
        p_clip[i] += ( modelViewprojection.m[i + j] * position_Vector.v[j]);
    }
}
float p_ndc[4];
p_ndc[0] = p_clip[0] / p_clip[3];
p_ndc[1] = p_clip[1] / p_clip[3];
p_ndc[2] = p_clip[2] / p_clip[3];
p_ndc[3] = p_clip[3] / p_clip[3];

GLint view[4]={0};
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,view);
CGRect rect =  CGRectMake(view[0], view[1], view[2], view[3]);
float x = (rect.origin.x + rect.size.width) *  (p_ndc[0] + 1) /2;
NSLog(@"Test x = %f",x);
```

Please find the attachment for the reference [image]

Comment: if you want pixel coordinates you also need the viewport offset and dimensions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply...Yes I have the viewport values and scale of rectangle...I did not get what dimensions is  ?

Comment: viewport dimensions are in screen pixels; possibly with a factor of 2 or 4 added if a hi-DPI display is involved and your application doesn't report it's hi-DPI aware. Vertex position coordinates are arbitrary units and only through the transformation chain from model local space to view to projection to clip to device coordinates "some" sense of physical units are applied. But it's pretty much "whatever you want them to be", to be honest.

Comment: Thanks got the dimension concept

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the transformation steps:

```
p_clip = P · MV · p
p_ndc = p_clip/p_clip.w
p_viewport.xy = viewport.xy + viewport.wh · (p_ndc.xy + 1) / 2
```

Comment: @datenwoolf thank you very much..I am pretty new in the openGL..I understood the above code..I am not finding the way to convert it to ios 
      GLKMatrix4   modelView;
 GLKMatrix4   projection;
 GLint view[4]={0};
 glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,view);
 GLKMatrix4 modelviewprojectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projection, modelView);   I did not get the small p in intial stage and does p_clip is CGRect ?

Comment: p is for "vertex position" i.e. the coordinates of your rectangle corners. p_clip is p transformed into clip space and p_ndc is p_clip after the homogenous divide has been applied. GLKMatrix4 is not part of OpenGL, but comes from Apple's GLKit helper library (https://developer.apple.com/reference/glkit/glkmatrix4-pce), `P · MV · p` means, multiply p with MV, and the result of that then with `P`. Or you could first premultiply `P · MV` and then multiply `p` with that. The rest are just shorthands.

Comment: is vertex position means   static GLfloat rectVerts[] = {  -0.1f,  -0.1f, 0.0f,
        -0.1f,  0.1f, 0.0f,
        0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f,
        0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f };

Comment: @pritam001: Sort of. `rectVerts` is an array of scalars, and when you pass it to OpenGL (in code you've not shows), it's specified that groups of 3 scalars make up a single vertex' position vector. It could also be groups of 2 or 4, or just single scalars, but in your case it can be easily inferred from that there are 12 scalars and a rectangle has 4 vertices. 12/4=3. The transformation matrices are 4×4 so you have to pad the vertex vectors. The usual padding is rule is "everything zero except the last element which is set 1"

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks for clarification...I have added the objective-C implementation but I am getting very high values. Can you please review it ?  I appreciate your help on this

Comment: @pritam001: Please do such edits in your own original question, otherwise it could be mistaken for an answer, which in your case would have been misleading/wrong. The mistake you made is, that you used matrix-matrix multiplication in an attempt to transform single vectors. I see where you're coming from and actually in the case of a quad it'd actually work. But the idiomatic solution is to iterate in loop over the individual vectors and to a vector-matrix multiplication.

Comment: @datenwolf I edited the question code...I think I am making some mistake in multiplication..some weird results are showing.....Can you please check it  ?